# SAML purpose and authentication in azure AD

Tags: azure-active-directory, saml, azure-ad-msal

I have to use Azure Active Directory for authentication to my web application.

In my company it was suggested to use SAML instead of oauth and I am very new to SAML.

Question:

1. Is the purpose of SAML is only to authenticate or there is any more functionality?
2. There are documents to use SAML in enterprise application. So,How to implement saml from app registration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. SAML SSO is a form of delegated authentication. The user is authenticated at the identity provider site (eg Azure AD) which sends a SAML assertion containing user identity information to the service provider site. The service provider trusts this information and establishes a local authentication session for the user using the information contained in the SAML assertion. SAML assertions often contain the user's email address but any user identity information may be included. This is the primary use case for SAML and in many instances the only one supported.
2. Most platforms have SAML libraries etc available. It's strongly recommended you use one of these rather than trying to implement SAML yourself.

Comment: Second the "use a library".